Raydium new pools monitoring CLMM tokens
As a measurement for new tokens, I use this dex screener's page.
By monitoring program id 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 with initialize2 command for some reason I can't get most of those tokens — as well as with Helios webhook.
By using bloxroute API for new pools I can get most of them except tokens marked as "CLMM" on DexScreener are very rarely caught.
What is the reason for this? Do I need to monitor different addresses and for different commands? Or what are the other ways to get all of those tokens?
P.S. I checked on of the CLMM tokens (3WjgCEDr8xZCs4NrxaB4CHG3jZagcJCYzxv9oC149n9D) and I see it interacts with 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 but in the same time there is no information about it in logs from events collected from api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

Sorry, what is your question? Are you trying to get metadata for newly tokens added on dexscreener? Or to check where was the pool created?

I want to get mint of the token as soon as pool created

try using gecko terminal API , i used this one and it was big help for me, especially for newly added tokens
edit: oh so you wanna fetch newly added tokens on dexscreener and get their mint address, right?

I think for CLMM, you can monitor CLMM program (CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK) mentioned here . If you monitor " Instruction: CreatePool" instruction then new mint will be present in that instruction. Maybe you can try that.
